# Angular: serialize/unserialize in JSON HttpRequest and HttpResponse object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want caching into the "[localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)" the [HttpRequest](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest) and [HttpResponse](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse) classes from `@angular/common/http`.

The `localstorage` only accept `string`, therefore i want serialize/unserialize both objects (HttpRequest and HttpResponse) with `JSON.stringfy()` and `JSON.parse()`.

The problem is `HttpRequest` and `HttpResponse` are both complex class with some [ES6 Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (eg. [HttpHeaders](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders)) and some getter/setter function, with `JSON.stringfy()` and `JSON.parse()` the serialization/unserialization don't return the same object and some information are lost.

There is a way for serialize/unserialize `HttpRequest` and `HttpResponse` class?

I'm searching for a complete serialization/unserialization (headers, params, body, etc)

In this example there is two method for serialize and unserialize HttpRequest, eg.:

```
function serializeRequest(angularRequest: HttpRequest): string {
  return null; // to implement
}
function unserializeRequest(jsonRequest: string): HttpRequest {
  return null; // to implement
}

// this is an example of request
const originalRequest = new HttpRequest('POST', 'https://angular.io/docs?foo=bar', {foo: true}, {
  params: new HttpParams().set('verbose', 'true'),
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    BAR: 'baz',
  }),
  reportProgress: true,
  responseType: 'json',
  withCredentials: true
});

// serializeRequest trasform HttpRequest in json format
const jsonRequest: string = serializeRequest(originalRequest);

// unserializeRequest trasform json format to HttpRequest
const unserializedRequest : HttpRequest = unserializeRequest(jsonRequest);

// unserializedRequest as same object of originalRequest
expect(originalRequest).toEqual(unserializedRequest);
```

the same serialization/unserialization for the response

```
function serializeResponse(angularResponse: HttpResponse): string {
  return null; // to implement
}
function unserializeResponse(jsonResponse: string): HttpResponse {
  return null; // to implement
}

// this is an example of response
const originalResponse = new HttpResponse({
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    BAR: 'baz',
  }),
  status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  url: 'https://angular.io/docs',
  body: {foo: true}}
);

// serializeResponse trasform HttpResponse in json format
const jsonResponse: string = serializeResponse(originalRequest);

// unserializeResponse trasform json format to HttpResponse 
const unserializedResponse: HttpResponse = unserializeResponse(jsonResponse);

// unserializedResponse as same object of originalResponse
expect(originalResponse).toEqual(unserializedResponse);
```

Comment: did you try [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) you can intercept all request and response header, body and params etc

Comment: Yes, the point is serialize/unserialize request/response

Comment: Why are you trying to cache http request & response to local storage ? What is the use case? For in memory caching you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cacheable its really simple & useful Library.

Comment: @Simone Nigro Do you want to serialize the class or the response? And also, what's your motivation?, maybe we can workaround this :)

Comment: I need to serialize and unserialize to/from string both class (response/request) . The motivation is store both class into localstorage, for persistent cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I would recommend a [Service Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) for Caching, the easiest way that I know is to clone the request/response and then get their information:

```
function serializeRequest(req: HttpRequest<any>): string {
    const request = req.clone(); // Make a clone, useful for doing destructive things
    return JSON.stringify({
        headers: Object.fromEntries( // Just a helper to make this into an object, not really required but makes the output nicer
            request.headers.keys.map( // Get all of the headers
                (key: string) => [key, request.headers.getAll(key)] // Get all of the corresponding values for the headers
            )
        ),
        method: request.method, // The Request Method, e.g. GET, POST, DELETE
        url: request.url, // The URL
        params: Object.fromEntries( // Just a helper to make this into an object, not really required but makes the output nicer
            request.headers.keys.map( // Get all of the headers
                (key: string) => [key, request.headers.getAll(key)] // Get all of the corresponding values for the headers
            )
        ), // The request parameters
        withCredentials: request.withCredentials, // Whether credentials are being sent
        respnseType: request.responseType, // The response type
        body: request.serializeBody() // Serialize the body, all well and good since we are working on a clone
    })
}
```

In a similar fashion we can serialize the response as well (assuming `T` is JSON compatible, a fair assumption in an HTTP Request):

```
function serializeResponse(res: HttpResponse<any>): string {
    const response = res.clone();
    return JSON.stringify({
        headers: Object.fromEntries( // Just a helper to make this into an object, not really required but makes the output nicer
            response.headers.keys.map( // Get all of the headers
                (key: string) => [key, response.headers.getAll(key)] // Get all of the corresponding values for the headers
            )
        ),
        status: response.status,
        statusText: response.statusText,
        url: response.url,
        body: response // Serialize the body, all well and good since we are working on a clone
    })
}
```

And then, since we saved all required information, deserialization is a walk in the park:

```
function deserializeRequest<T = any>(req: string): HttpRequest<T> {
    const request = JSON.parse(req);
    const headers = new HttpHeaders(request.headers);
    const params = new HttpParams(); // Probably some way to make this a one-liner, but alas, there are no good docs
    for(let parameter in request.params){
        request.params[parameter].forEach((paramValue: string) => params.append(parameter, paramValue));
    }
    return new HttpRequest(request.method, request.url, request.body, {
        headers,
        params,
        respnseType: request.respnseType,
        withCredentials: request.withCredentials
    });
}

function deserializeResponse<T = any>(res: string): HttpResponse<T> {
    const response = JSON.parse(res);
    const headers = new HttpHeaders(response.headers);
    return new HttpRequest({
        headers,
        body: response.body,
        status: response.status,
        statusText: response.statusText,
        url: response.url,
    });
}
```

[Playground of the whole thing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwFB1XAEjGYBKBTAZ0gDsC8AaDLXPARwFdCZLNt08BDAEzygJeoAFDlA4gCSAL5wAZlAgg4AcgACHYgHN6AGxEB6AMYKQEYnoAW1JQG4kSGfWIGYwU3DJRgHbcABeefAYmAAooOgAuKmxAxgIYAB51AE8APgBKSLjPTUQUNCNSeDCguLgAXjhigDoDbVM8YLTrOD09OABZDgBrPDgOOFr6ynoyB21ZaDguCGAcniz6Z2AAN16Yc1mNCTRKvBh6KGI4ACkAZQB5ADkqrM3gGSTg5B2d804ePkjzgCMAKzxnFU5AoAKLEGCeQjBFptY4jeD9N7aMC8OAwCBwEDdNYbAhwWbovpHCB-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-CRgA6m8PK5gYTkuC5fRhKyeDpmQ4LnpJpB4J2SQoluJTSpJphkNFKL7nAWmJZFaIxXg57fPWDF2c2HjWX4eAAEIFY0kanLwpX+Hm+VcEklAxnAhmfuM6gshoED1u4swiu1vQiL0hnQF06ZuP0gzELlOySKWkh2A4TguG4JXeGV+AppFoSEJErA0LtZCJMQqQZO4do5M8+RJdSJ29BUyY1HUc2NLYOxhPshwnBc1y3Jo9yPLd4rKbe-z3vIj7gpCBDqrC8J9PmX65j+2JGv++LgkBxKgZQ4G7JB2kwXBgq-khvL8mhGFQOeX2ECQZBetRCoES2REI1GZGxmJxrKfTFr0Yx9qOi6bq7I9LNmnxMCBto9FCRqpG6rzeYSYzqbprJ8mKfzBYqcWakWhW55xBw+y2ZlzPm5blaWrbIydngAAeMBblLjsEM7bv2xaG4e0zw57nlBWB0lvQarVnhbQ1lFNS1qvDXq3VwL1-UEINY0jYF41QJNOTTQMb3zWgi1SCtjhLG48x1bHARcXE8SduURKpPttAi5ol1Hb2Tedk6oMDPdRXwBUZxXFUl58A0xRNEWBSlMprdzYZURgOwrMdzuynzzsi-wNP14r3ga9HcIojiB9kaCPI3wcN8dLuAoY0cPS6M9JjeL9PUAC0PhzSgJQeCuoOCuS8jnXolI059RZNMAwhsFJQGCNoHUR99K5lmKPKeekCBpCHgzeKODL4EGdOgvYvAwxAmgCCDgBhzDBGCOggAalmPAXdmJi3QQqIiKJiBcCYXpChQDdKX1YXJPAaQ95lyLN9A4RxV7rz7jAbenpWx1i4JxIhe5sEJ0oAQtAyk-bim4cYiUjNIopXYdgiKyUcpmJ2A5cw5lYKWT8jZOKO4nEuJ4M5GyRZFq2GWvYKu60ji1xjj4fwO0g7N1bskFI+1bKA2YodagMSI7N0HgvEe1snp-UntPMgSTpGoAPlRM0J8z7UE3maJJQdpbylKbsH6CjT5KMbiogxqAjGh2auHSKVQ9FmxgBbEYAybajLtiMsZ3tXbu0lg0r2PtmDngDosiOu4oDaDMYEqQQA) (although, regrettably the angular types do not load correctly)

> Note that I have not tested this in any environment, so this is provided AS-IS, and I am not sure how `expect` would handle two `HttpHeaders`/`HttpParams`, especially since they may not have the exact same order.

Comment: `request.serializeBody()` will return `ArrayBuffer | Blob | FormData | string | null`. This solution won't work for all this types, will it?

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to serialize the `HttpRequest` then the class itself provides `serializeBody()` method, [here](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#serializebody)

Comment: serialize only the body... i'm seraching for a complete serialization/unserialization headers, params, body, etc)

Answer (score -1):

The below mentioned way is the best way of serialize the HttpResponse in Angular. **res.json()** function will show you the body,headers and params.

```
this.http.get('/app/lists.json').map((res:Response) => res.json());
```

Comment: I'm searching for a complete serialization/unserialization

Comment: I understood your scenario. Kindly check this  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-serialization-deserialization?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts . I hope this will help you out.